# How to display attachment image on custom community page

Tags: visualforce, community

I need to display an image attached to a custom object to all community portal visitors (logged in and not). I've managed to get the url, but it only works when I log in to SF first with my admin account. For community users the link doesn't work and only a 'broken image' icon is shown

Comment: So you are using `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attachment.id}`, correct? Are you adjusting the domain to use the community domain and url rather than `na10.salesforce.com` (or what ever pod instance you are on).

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)` function and it will always return the correct URL.

Comment: Any idea on how this can be done in lightning. Thanks.